# Radius and interval of convergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How to find the radius of convergence and interval of convergence of the following power series?

$$\sum{x^{n!}}$$

and

$$ \sum{\frac{1}{n^{\sqrt{n}}} x^n} $$

Comment: A [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/228852/26872).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first one just use the ratio test:

$$\frac{x^{(n+1)!}}{x^{n!}}=x^{(n+1)!-n!}=x^{n!((n+1)-1)}=x^{n\cdot n!}\;.$$

Now what’s $$\lim_{n\to\infty}|x|^{n\cdot n!}\;?$$

Comment: @Babak: Shh! ;-) Yes, it is.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Use the [root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) for the second series and note that

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{n^{\sqrt{n}}}\right)^{1/n}=1. $$

Comment: Hint:I think the following link will be helpful to answer the first question...http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252833/finding-the-radius-of-convergence-of-sum-0-inftyzn/252839#252839

Comment: @learner: I did not answered the first!!

Comment: sorry,sir.I apologize..